# Run Coded UI test from console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

I'm fighting running a coded ui test from a console application.

I did the following (As the internet says)

Solution with 2 Projects:
ColorChanger.app /
ColorChanger.test

the console application has a reference to the test project and to Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting

I would like to call the test like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Playback.Initialize();
        var test = new CodedUITest1();
        test.change();
        Playback.Cleanup();
    }
```

I get the error "System.IO.FileNotFoundException

```
Die Datei oder Assembly \"Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Framework, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a\" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Framework, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"}
```

I'm sorry it's in german but I'm shure you'll get it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update the internal references as well.. . Try this http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2010/07/15/running-codedui-test-from-another-application/

Comment: This is actually exactly the site I used to do this... 
I can't figure out how to add these ?!

- Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.CodeGeneration.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Framework.dll
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.dll

What is the difference of public and private assemblies ? It seems I can only see the public ones ?

Comment: can you not find the assemblies under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies" ??... You can add a reference as like this:  In Solution Explorer, right-click the project node and click Add Reference.
In the Add Reference dialog box, select the tab indicating the type of component you want to reference.
Select the components you want to reference, and then click OK.

Comment: Alright I had to add these assemblies via the "Browse" button and search them in the directory... Is it normal that these are not listet in the "assemblies" -> "extensions" tab like everything else ? 
But thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes it's normal !! They are more like reference of your references