# How do I playback already created CodedUI Test Methods from a Default.aspx file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

I have a CodedUiTest project with several Test Methods inside of it. All of these Test Methods can be called manually from inside of Visual Studios, but I am trying to build an interface that can call the various tests from a web browser.

I have added a web project inside the solution, and have successfully referenced the test methods from the Default.aspx.cs file no problem. The issue is that once the Test Method is called I get "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.WindowsStoreUtility".

I am trying to add a reference manually, but I cannot find out where this reference comes from. I have looked in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies and do not see it anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might find some of the Q&As here about running Coded UI from a console or standalone application relevant.

Comment: Try this! http://stackoverflow.com/a/37036537/5212566